# Multiple ring buffer on point-shape error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, buffer, error-999999

I need to calculate multiple ring-buffers, but every time I try, arcgis produces a failure:

Executing (Multiple Ring Buffer): MultipleRingBuffer Y:\GIS\RDY\clip\sn_clip.shp Y:\GIS\RDY\sn_clip_ring.shp 100;250;500;750;1000;1250;1500;1750;2000;2250;2500;2750;3000;3250;3500;3750;4000;4250;4500;4750;5000;5250;5500;5750;6000;6250;6500;6750;7000;7250;7500;7750;8000;8250;8500;8750;9000;9250;9500;9750;10000;10250;10500;10750;1100 Meters distance ALL FULL
Start Time: Fri Feb 15 12:03:02 2013
Running script MultipleRingBuffer...
ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
The table was not found.
The table was not found. [union]
The table was not found.
The table was not found. [union]
Invalid Topology [Topoengine error.]
Failed to execute (Union).

Completed script MultipleRingBuffer...
Failed to execute (Multiple Ring Buffer).
Failed at Fri Feb 15 13:58:58 2013 (Elapsed Time: 1 hours 55 minutes 56 seconds)

I don't get it. Can anyone help me with this? Note that I'm not used to python.

Comment: What version of ArcGIS are you using?

Comment: couldn't help but notice that your last increment doesn't follow from the previous ie 10750;1100 is 1100 supposed to be 11000 ?

Comment: @ Mapperz: i'm using ArcMap 10.1

Comment: @Dan Patterson: thanks for that announcement, but that's not the error.

Comment: Have you tried selecting out a single feature from Y:\GIS\RDY\clip\sn_clip.shp into a new much smaller shapefile and tried MultipleRingBuffer on that to see if your procedure or data seems to be the issue?

Comment: @PolyGeo: thanks a lot for this one. tried it with just one feature - it worked perfectly. the same with 4 features, that are close to each other, so the different rings have to collide - again it worked perfectly. trying a new run on the whole data at the moment. i'm wondering if it could be the fact that the data i want to buffer has >5500 features?

Comment: It still does not work, still the same Error999999. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Has there been a resolution for this problem? I am having a similar issue although I am getting 'append' error instead. Seems like a new problem to me, I have used this tool a couple months ago without any problem.